# Is it incorrect if we just say "some people [may be / are] very busy" without a time adverb

Tags: grammar, tense

I tried to comfort Jan by saying:
"I will let you know once she receives the card. Don't worry! The postmen may have been very busy."

I understand that "I will be very busy tomorrow" is alright, 
so is "The postmen will be very busy tomorrow".

Now given the following two sentences (1) and (2):
(1): The postmen may be very busy
(2): The postmen are very busy

I am not sure if it is grammatically incorrect by just saying "The postmen may be very busy" or "The postmen are very busy" without a single-word time adverb.

Comment: I think they *do* make sense without time adverbs, especially when there is an emphasis on the "are". Or maybe I'm only pointing at when they're omitted intentionally, like when they're obvious.

Comment: In many contexts it's perfectly normal for English to use Present Tense to reference future actions/events. Both your examples would be fine with ***right now*** instead of ***tomorrow***, but it would have to be *... **were** very busy **yesterday***.

Comment: I do not see any problem here. Why would you *need* an adverb of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are both correct.  "Busy" is a simple adjective.

The postmen can be "very busy" the same way they can be "very tall" or "very drunk".